ssh-keygen on Ipad 1
I have a Ipad 1 ios 5.1.1 with Cydia jailbreak, the normal user on Ipad is "mobile", and is not possible to adduser. My problem is that I want to connect to a linux server with the following syntax:
ssh max@192.168.1.22 without enter password.
I have generated from user mobile the key with ssh-keygen and added to authorized_keys to the server, but is always asking password.
Thanks in advance

I fix the problem, I generate 3 keys with -t dsa | ecdsa | ed25519 and added to pub key to authorized_keys and now it's working.
I don't know the reason !!! ... but it's working
